# Loop doesn't see value changed by other thread without a print statement

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, busy-waiting

In my code I have a loop that waits for some state to be changed from a different thread. The other thread works, but my loop never sees the changed value. **It waits forever.** However, when I put a `System.out.println` statement in the loop, it suddenly works! Why?

---

The following is an example of my code:

```
class MyHouse {
    boolean pizzaArrived = false;

    void eatPizza() {
        while (pizzaArrived == false) {
            //System.out.println("waiting");
        }

        System.out.println("That was delicious!");
    }

    void deliverPizza() {
        pizzaArrived = true;
    }
}
```

While the while loop is running, I call `deliverPizza()` from a different thread to set the `pizzaArrived` variable. But the loop only works when I uncomment the `System.out.println("waiting");` statement. What's going on?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The JVM is allowed to assume that other threads do not change the `pizzaArrived` variable during the loop. In other words, it can hoist the `pizzaArrived == false` test outside the loop, optimizing this:

```
while (pizzaArrived == false) {}
```

into this:

```
if (pizzaArrived == false) while (true) {}
```

which is an infinite loop.

To ensure that changes made by one thread are visible to other threads you must always add some **synchronization** between the threads. The simplest way to do this is to make the shared variable `volatile`:

```
volatile boolean pizzaArrived = false;
```

Making a variable `volatile` guarantees that different threads will see the effects of each other's changes to it. This prevents the JVM from caching the value of `pizzaArrived` or hoisting the test outside the loop. Instead, it must read the value of the real variable every time.

(More formally, `volatile` creates a *happens-before* relationship between accesses to the variable. This means that [all other work a thread did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738651/volatile-variable-explanation-in-java-docs) before delivering the pizza is also visible to the thread receiving the pizza, even if those other changes are not to `volatile` variables.)

[Synchronized methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) are used principally to implement mutual exclusion (preventing two things happening at the same time), but they also have all the same side-effects that `volatile` has. Using them when reading and writing a variable is another way to make the changes visible to other threads:

```
class MyHouse {
    boolean pizzaArrived = false;

    void eatPizza() {
        while (getPizzaArrived() == false) {}
        System.out.println("That was delicious!");
    }

    synchronized boolean getPizzaArrived() {
        return pizzaArrived;
    }

    synchronized void deliverPizza() {
        pizzaArrived = true;
    }
}
```

---

### The effect of a print statement

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` object. The methods of `PrintStream` are synchronized like this:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

The synchronization prevents `pizzaArrived` being cached during the loop. *Strictly speaking, **both** threads must synchronize on the same object* to guarantee that changes to the variable are visible. (For example, calling `println` after setting `pizzaArrived` and calling it again before reading `pizzaArrived` would be correct.) If only one thread synchronizes on a particular object, the JVM is allowed to ignore it. In practice, the JVM is not smart enough to prove that other threads won't call `println` after setting `pizzaArrived`, so it assumes that they might. Therefore, it cannot cache the variable during the loop if you call `System.out.println`. That's why loops like this work when they have a print statement, although it is not a correct fix.

Using `System.out` is not the only way to cause this effect, but it is the one people discover most often, when they are trying to debug why their loop doesn't work!

---

### The bigger problem

`while (pizzaArrived == false) {}` is a busy-wait loop. That's bad! While it waits, it hogs the CPU, which slows down other applications, and increases the power usage, temperature, and fan speed of the system. Ideally, we would like the loop thread to sleep while it waits, so it does not hog the CPU.

Here are some ways to do that:

#### Using wait/notify

A low-level solution is to [use the wait/notify methods of `Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536692/a-simple-scenario-using-wait-and-notify-in-java):

```
class MyHouse {
    boolean pizzaArrived = false;

    void eatPizza() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (!pizzaArrived) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        System.out.println("That was delicious!");
    }

    void deliverPizza() {
        synchronized (this) {
            pizzaArrived = true;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

In this version of the code, the loop thread calls [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--), which puts the thread the sleep. It will not use any CPU cycles while sleeping. After the second thread sets the variable, it calls [`notifyAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--) to wake up any/all threads which were waiting on that object. This is like having the pizza guy ring the doorbell, so you can sit down and rest while waiting, instead of standing awkwardly at the door.

When calling wait/notify on an object you must hold the synchronization lock of that object, which is what the above code does. You can use any object you like so long as both threads use the same object: here I used `this` (the instance of `MyHouse`). Usually, two threads would not be able to enter synchronized blocks of the same object simultaneously (which is part of the purpose of synchronization) but it works here because a thread temporarily releases the synchronization lock when it is inside the `wait()` method.

#### BlockingQueue

A [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is used to implement producer-consumer queues. "Consumers" take items from the front of the queue, and "producers" push items on at the back. An example:

```
class MyHouse {
    final BlockingQueue<Object> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    void eatFood() throws InterruptedException {
        // take next item from the queue (sleeps while waiting)
        Object food = queue.take();
        // and do something with it
        System.out.println("Eating: " + food);
    }

    void deliverPizza() throws InterruptedException {
        // in producer threads, we push items on to the queue.
        // if there is space in the queue we can return immediately;
        // the consumer thread(s) will get to it later
        queue.put("A delicious pizza");
    }
}
```

Note: The `put` and `take` methods of `BlockingQueue` can throw `InterruptedException`s, which are checked exceptions which must be handled. In the above code, for simplicity, the exceptions are rethrown. You might prefer to catch the exceptions in the methods and retry the put or take call to be sure it succeeds. Apart from that one point of ugliness, `BlockingQueue` is very easy to use.

No other synchronization is needed here because a `BlockingQueue` makes sure that everything threads did before putting items in the queue is visible to the threads taking those items out.

#### Executors

`Executor`s are like ready-made `BlockingQueue`s which execute tasks. Example:

```
// A "SingleThreadExecutor" has one work thread and an unlimited queue
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Runnable eatPizza = () -> { System.out.println("Eating a delicious pizza"); };
Runnable cleanUp = () -> { System.out.println("Cleaning up the house"); };

// we submit tasks which will be executed on the work thread
executor.execute(eatPizza);
executor.execute(cleanUp);
// we continue immediately without needing to wait for the tasks to finish
```

For details see the doc for [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), and [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

#### Event handling

Looping while waiting for the user to click something in a UI is wrong. Instead, use the event handling features of the UI toolkit. [In Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), for example:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    // This event listener is run when the button is clicked.
    // We don't need to loop while waiting.
    label.setText("Button was clicked");
});
```

Because the event handler runs on the event dispatch thread, doing long work in the event handler blocks other interaction with the UI until the work is finished. Slow operations can be started on a new thread, or dispatched to a waiting thread using one of the above techniques (wait/notify, a `BlockingQueue`, or `Executor`). You can also use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), which is designed exactly for this, and automatically supplies a background worker thread:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
JButton button = new JButton("Calculate answer");

// Add a click listener for the button
button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

    // Defines MyWorker as a SwingWorker whose result type is String:
    class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<String,Void> {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // This method is called on a background thread.
            // You can do long work here without blocking the UI.
            // This is just an example:
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return "Answer is 42";
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // This method is called on the Swing thread once the work is done
            String result;
            try {
                result = get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            label.setText(result); // will display "Answer is 42"
        }
    }

    // Start the worker
    new MyWorker().execute();
});
```

#### Timers

To perform periodic actions, you can use a [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). It is easier to use than writing your own timing loop, and easier to start and stop. This demo prints the current time once per second:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

Each `java.util.Timer` has its own background thread which is used to execute its scheduled `TimerTask`s. Naturally, the thread sleeps between tasks, so it does not hog the CPU.

In Swing code, there is also a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which is similar, but it executes the listener on the Swing thread, so you can safely interact with Swing components without needing to manually switch threads:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, (ActionEvent e) -> {
    frame.setTitle(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
});
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

#### Other ways

If you are writing multithreaded code, it is worth exploring the classes in these packages to see what is available:

- [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)
- [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)
- [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html)

And also see the [Concurrency section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) of the Java tutorials. Multithreading is complicated, but there is lots of help available!

Comment: Very professional answer, after reading this no misconception is left on my mind, thank you

Comment: Awesome answer. I am working with Java threads for quite a while and still learned something here (`wait()` releases the synchronization lock!).

Comment: Thank you, Boann! Great answer, it's like a full article with examples! Yes, also liked "wait() releases the synchronization lock"

Comment: ```java
public class ThreadTest {
    private static boolean flag = false;

    private static class Reader extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(flag == false) {}
            System.out.println(flag);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Reader().start();
        flag = true;
    }
}
```
@Boann, this code doesn't  hoist the `pizzaArrived == false` test outside the loop, and loop can see flag changed by main thread,why?

Comment: @gaussclb `flag = true;` executes too quickly, before your loop thread has started. Insert a `Thread.sleep(1000);` before `flag = true;` and you should see an infinite loop.

Comment: @Boann, I have decompiled the code above, and don't find any hoisting `pizzaArrived == false` outside the loop, what's wrong?

Comment: @gaussclb If you mean that you decompiled a class file, correct. The Java compiler does almost no optimization. The hoisting is done by the JVM. You need to disassemble the native machine code. Try: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly

Comment: @Boann, can the implementation of `synchronized` in println be relied on to exist?

Comment: @Pacerier No. You can't rely on println to use `synchronized`, nor can you rely on `synchronized` to have such an effect, except when all involved threads are synchronizing on the same object.