# Android Screen shots handler

Tags: android

I have create the Handler inside the activity onCreate method. This Hanlder is responsible to take screen shots after 10 seconds. Inside the run method I have used while(flag==true) and screen the capture util flag==false, But this stuck my activity. I can not able to work. And it take the screen shot over again and again of same image because of actvity is stuck. 
How I can work with my screen and what I am doing handler take the screen shot after 10 seconds?
The while loop stuck my app.

It Take picture but I am not able to work with my activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    flag = true;


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (flag == true) {
                String SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/re/";
                // Get root view
                View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                // Create the bitmap to use to draw the screenshot
                final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                        view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

                // Get current theme to know which background to use
                final Theme theme = getTheme();
                final TypedArray ta = theme
                        .obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.windowBackground });
                final int res = ta.getResourceId(0, 0);
                final Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(res);

                // Draw background
                background.draw(canvas);

                // Draw views
                view.draw(canvas);
                FileOutputStream fos = null;

                try {
                    final File sddir = new File(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS);
                    if (!sddir.exists()) {
                        sddir.mkdirs();
                    }

                    fos = new FileOutputStream(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS + x
                            + ".jpg");
                    x++;
                    if (fos != null) {
                        if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                                90, fos)) {
                            Log.d("ScreenShot", "Compress/Write failed");
                        }
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }

    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've written ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement)

Comment: Try `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);` after definind your runnable seperately.

Comment: when I make separate runnable it give exception. IllegalArgumentException width and height > 0 "in createBitmap", Its mean its not take the view of current screen to get the height and width in separate ruunable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or other thread. The `postDelayed()` function attaches to the main UI thread and locks up your app until `run()` is finished (which never happens because flag never equals false so the while loop becomes infinite?).

Here is an example using the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor:

```
private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    flag = true;

    exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
    long interval = (long) 10; // 10 seconds for you
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new savePicTask(), 0, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

class savePicTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (flag == true) {
            String SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/re/";
            // Get root view
            View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            // Create the bitmap to use to draw the screenshot
            final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                    view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

            // Get current theme to know which background to use
            final Theme theme = getTheme();
            final TypedArray ta = theme
                    .obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.windowBackground });
            final int res = ta.getResourceId(0, 0);
            final Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(res);

            // Draw background
            background.draw(canvas);

            // Draw views
            view.draw(canvas);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;

            try {
                final File sddir = new File(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS);
                if (!sddir.exists()) {
                    sddir.mkdirs();
                }

                fos = new FileOutputStream(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS + x
                        + ".jpg");
                x++;
                if (fos != null) {
                    if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)) {
                        Log.d("ScreenShot", "Compress/Write failed");
                    }
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }       
}
```

EDIT 1:
This code works for me except I am using

```
numberOfSeconds = 0.5;
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
long interval = (long) (1000* numberOfSeconds); // numberOfSeconds = 10 for you
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new savePicTask(), 0, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

And instead of taking a screenshot I am taking a picture with the camera. So I'm not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: while loop false is not matter here. When user click on record button it going to take the screen shots of user screen, When user click on stop I will make while flag=flase and stop the thread. Here I want only that why it not make my activity workable. I can not do anything on it. It stuck and backend it takes images

Comment: Yeah, I think it's because you are running the screenshots on the main UI thread. You need to run your screenshot logic on a [background thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) (using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), or [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), or something comparable)

Comment: Your code even not capturing one picture. even not creating the folder.

Comment: Whoops -- Did you put the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor as a member outside onCreate()?

Comment: Do you have any output -- errors, print statements, anything? This works for me except I am using it to take a picture every 0.5 seconds and store it to SD card.

Comment: Its not print any log I have check. But I have resolved my issue using time and handler. Thanks Bro for Help. I will run your code and reply your may be I make any mistake in your code. Thanks Again for Help.