# Thread stops when I don't constantly sysout

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm currently writing a client-server application with Java on the client side. When starting up the client, I start a thread that runs in the background and sends/receives data when the GUI asks for it. The GUI doesn't change anything in the network thread object, but sets a state in a "monitor" object that the network thread watches in a loop.

Now the problem is: when I constantly System.out.println() something in the client loop, the thread keeps running and sends/receives data as it should. But when I do not Sysout anything in that loop, the client loop stops and thus nothing happens when I attempt to send something to the server.

Here's the run()-method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        srv_loop: while(true) {
            System.out.println("Looping"); // When removing this line, it all breaks down and nothing happens when I attempt to send to the server.
            if(!monitor.message.equals("")) {
                if(monitor.message.equals("CLOSE")) {
                    break srv_loop;
                }
                outStream.writeInt(monitor.message.length());
                System.out.println("Wrote length: " + monitor.message.length());
                outStream.writeBytes(monitor.message + '\n');
                System.out.println("Wrote message: " + monitor.message);
                String answer = inStream.readLine();
                System.out.println("Got answer: " + answer);

                if(answer.equals("ACK")) {
                    monitor.message = "";
                } else if(answer.equals("FAIL")) {
                    monitor.message = "FAIL";
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("out");
}
```

Now I could of course leave the sysout there and it will work, but I don't want to have my terminal run amok all the time when I use my program. This seems so strange to me, I really have no clue why this happens. The only thing sysout does is to print and make a little delay, however Thread.sleep(100) does not work either.

I know I should have taken a more event-driven approach and that this is really not a good way to write a client in Java, but I only use Java to prototype -- Swing GUI works anywhere and that's all I need right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: you only need to label a loop if you are trying to `break` or `continue` from within a nested loop and need to refer to the outer loop.

Comment: Looks like another case of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269174/questions-about-threadloop-not-working-without-print-statement which answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement