# Puzzled by Java: boolean assignment fails in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, variable-assignment

I am quite puzzled by certain behavior in Java, and I was wondering if somebody could provide an explanation. I am trying to set a `boolean` value to `true` to stop a thread, but assignment fails. Consider the following example:

```
public class Temp {

public class Unstoppable implements Runnable {
    public boolean stop=false;
    private int ctr=0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!stop) {
            stop |= doSomething();
        }
    }

    public boolean doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Still running "+ctr++);

        // some other logic here could decide that it's time to stop
        // especially if Unstoppable would be an abstract class and doSomething() an abstract function  
        return false;
    }

    public void stop() {
        stop=true;
    }
}

public void start() {
    // start thread with Unstoppable
    Unstoppable st = new Unstoppable();
    new Thread(st).start();

    // wait for a while
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // try to stop the thread
    st.stop(); // assignment fails, variable 'stop' is still false after this call so Unstoppable never stops
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Temp t = new Temp();
    t.start();
}
}
```

Trying to assign the value `true` in the `stop()` function simply fails and the thread keeps running. I found out that changing the code to below resolves the problem:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while(!stop) {
            // without   stop |=   the thread DOES stop
            doSomething();
        }
    }
```

but I can't understand why.

More bizarrely, the code change below also resolves the problem:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!stop) {
            stop |= doSomething();

            // printing here does also result in the thread stopping!
            System.out.println("Still running "+ctr++);
        }
    }

    public boolean doSomething() {
        // some other logic here could decide that it's time to stop
        // especially if Unstoppable would be an abstract class and doSomething() an abstract function  
        return false;
    }
```

Although I can resolve the problem, I'd like to understand what's going on here. Thanks!

**Edit** 
Just some more clarification, I changed the code into the following:

```
public class Temp {

public class Unstoppable implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean stop=false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!stop) {
            System.out.println("A) stop="+stop);
            stop |= doSomething();
            System.out.println("C) stop="+stop);
        }
    }

    public boolean doSomething() {
        while(!stop) {
        }
        System.out.println("B) stop="+stop);
        // some other logic here could decide that it's time to stop
        // especially if Unstoppable would be an abstract class and doSomething() an abstract function  
        return false;
    }

    public void setStop(boolean stop) {
        System.out.println("D) stop="+stop);
        this.stop=stop;
        System.out.println("E) stop="+stop);
    }
}

public void start() {
    // start thread with Unstoppable
    Unstoppable st = new Unstoppable();
    Thread t = new Thread(st);
    t.start();

    // wait for a while
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // try to stop the thread
    st.setStop(true); // assignment fails, variable 'stop' is still false after this call so Unstoppable never stops
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Temp t = new Temp();
    t.start();
}
}
```

This results in the following statements on the console:

```
A) stop=false
D) stop=true
E) stop=true
B) stop=true
C) stop=false
A) stop=false
```

The puzzlement was on statement C) stop=false. At B) it was true, the function then results false, and I would expect `true |= false` to result in `true`...

However, as slim showed, the left side of the |= was already evaluated by Java before doSomething() was called. Changing the code to :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(!stop) {
        boolean stopNow = doSomething();
        stop |= stopNow;
    }
}
```

Does result in the thread being stopped.

Comment: What if you make `stop` volatile?

Comment: tried that, doesn't help

Comment: When you say the assignment fails, what do you mean exactly? Only that the thread doesn't stop?

Comment: No, that the variable is still `false` after the statement `stop = true` is executed

Comment: Seems like a visibility problem. Try using `AtomicBoolean` instead.

Comment: By the way, I don't think the question is duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement. Defining `stop` as `volatile` doesn't help.

Comment: I vaguely remember there being a "thing" in Java in that if a thread's code is very short (as yours is), there's never a chance for another thread to affect it.  This is why your changes suddenly make it work.  I can't remember what the concept is called in order to Google it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stop |= foo()`

... is an abbreviation of:

```
boolean x = foo();
boolean y = stop || x;
stop = y;
```

Now consider two threads:

```
     Thread A                |  Thread B
1    boolean x = foo();      |
2    boolean y = stop || x;  |  
3                            |  stop = true;
4    stop = y                |
5    if(stop) { ... }
```

If `y` is `false`, then, when things happen in this order, thread B's assignment to `stop` (3) gets replaced by thread A's assignment (4), before the test (5).

This race condition happens even if `stop` is volatile, and even if you ignore the "weirdness" of variable visibility between threads.

The point is that `stop |= foo()` is not **atomic**, and so stuff can happen during its execution that screws up the apparent logic. This is why we have classes like `AtomicBoolean` which provide guaranteed atomic operations which you could use for this purpose.

```
  AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean();
  ...
  while(! stop.get()) {
      ...
      stop.compareAndSet(false, foo());
  }
```

Alternatively you could put the `|=` into a `synchronized` method, and make this the **only way** you ever assign `stop`:

```
   private synchronized stopIf(boolean doStop) {
        this.stop |= doStop;
   }
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually the case. If I try this: 

  `public boolean doSomething() {
   while(!stop) {
    System.out.println("Still running "+ctr++);
   }
   return false;
  }` the |= statement is never called, but `stop=true` still fails to actually change the value of `stop`

Comment: @hinsbergen in that case making it volatile will probably help.

Comment: No it doesn't, I tried it. And it's not a race condition, since putting an infinite while loop inside the doSomething prevents it from ever returning, and from |= ever being called. In this case nobody is ever changing the value of stop, except the failed attempt of the stop() function.

Comment: Just get rid of the 'stop |=' and have doSomething() on its own.  This will work.. I would also put a sleep in the main after you tell it to stop.  Sleep to wait for it to finish instead of exiting and having the shutdown of the execution happen at the same time as you're waiting for the thread to stop gracefully.

Comment: Also, private on the stop member variable, and only reference the value of stop through synchronized member functions.  public synchronized boolean getStop() ... public synchronized void setStop(boolean)

Comment: The point of the question was not on how to fix it, but to understand why `stop=true` can fail to change the value of the variable. By the way, making `stop` `private` didn't change the behavior, and synchronized getting and setting neither...

Comment: OK, got it now, indeed the left side of the |= statement is already evaluated by Java before doSomething() is called. I edited my post with some clarification.

Comment: Just a short final note: I think slim's breakdown of |= is actually the wrong way around, so `boolean y=stop` is first, and `boolean x=foo()` is called next.

Comment: @hinsbergen No. You can get your IDE to show you how it breaks down, by changing to `stop = stop || foo()` then repeatedly using the "extract local variable" refactoring.