# Thread safety of reads from and writes to a variable reference

Tags: java, multithreading

I've read [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), which states (among a few other things) that:

> Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables

So that means, assuming I understand this correctly, that the below code is thread safe without needing `volatile`, `synchronized`, or using a `Lock` class, since the actual assignment of `otherHashlist` to `hashlist` is atomic and the assignment from `hashlist` to `tempHashlist` is also atomic.

```
public class SomeClass
{
  private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>> hashlist = null;

  // ...Thread/Runnable logic to periodically call set()...

  private void set()
  {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>> otherHashlist = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>>();

    // ...populate otherHashlist...

    hashlist = otherHashlist;
  }

  public ArrayList<MyObject> get(int i)
  {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>> tempHashlist = hashlist;

    return new ArrayList<MyObject>(tempHashlist.get(i));
  }
}
```

Additionally, `hashlist` is never accessed in any way outside of `get()` and `set()`.  `set()` is also not able to be called, directly or indirectly, by anything outside of the class.  The ArrayList returned by `get()` is `new`, so operations that modify the ArrayList (set(), remove(), etc) will not affect the original ArrayList in `hashlist`.  I also have not defined any setter methods on `MyObject`, all of whose member variables are either `private final int`, `private final long`, or `private final String`.

So, my question then, is: Is this code actually thread safe?  Or is there some assumption I'm making/angle I'm missing that would make this unsafe?

Comment: Unrelated: why do you need the following line: `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyObject>> tempHashlist = hashlist;` when you can get directly from `hashlist` ?

Comment: Assigning all the elements of `hashlist` to a new ArrayList is definitely not atomic, and I wasn't sure what would happen if `set()` was called part way through constructing that new ArrayList.

Comment: The line I was referring to does nothing like assigning all the elements of hashlist to a new ArrayList - it's a reference assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't thread safe, because although setting the field is safe and won't cause overlapping updates, the changes may not actually be *visible* by other threads. That is, even if `Thread1` sets `hashlist` to something, `Thread2` may not *see* that change. This is because the JVM is allowed to optimize accesses to `hashlist` in `Thread2`, say copying the reference into a register so it doesn't need to do a `getfield` multiple times. In this case, when `Thread1` changes `hashlist`, `Thread2` can't see it, because it is no longer using the field, it is using a local copy of it, which it thinks *is* the field. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25425130/5684257) shows what can happen in cases like this.

The easiest thing to do is to label `hashlist` `volatile`, which means changes in one thread are actually seen by others.

Comment: `hashlist` never leaves `SomeClass`, the only thing ever returned is an `ArrayList<MyObject>`.

Comment: Doesn't matter; if a `SomeClass` is shared between threads and access to `hashlist` is unsynchronized (`volatile` is a form of synchronization), the problem persists.

Comment: @HTNW sorry for being pedantic: volatile is *not* a form of synchronization, volatile mechanism makes sure modifications of a field are visible to all threads, it's a good solution if only one thread updates a field and multiple threads reads it, but it's not a synchronization mechanism, synchronization is stronger since it's supports writes from multiple threads.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, I'll correct my statement and say that there needs to be some *happens-before* relation between writes and reads to `hashlist`, which is provided by `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is the expected behavior...

If every thread has its own instance of `SomeClass` - it's thread-safe. So let's assume multiple threads have the same instance:

Now say that two threads call `set` simultaneously, and right after one of them executes the assignment: `hashlist = otherHashlist;` the other thread is doing the exact same thing (with different content probably).
This means that two consecutive calls to `get(i)` might return different results, which means consistency is not being kept. Further, since threads have local-caching, it could be that some threads will see an older (stale) copy of `hashlist`.

Is this an accepted behavior ? if yes (which is a bit weird IMO), then you're good.

I highly recommend reading: [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://inbravo.github.io/docs/refer/java-concurrency.pdf) by Brian Goetz, around chapter: "3.5. Safe Publication"

Comment: There will only be one instance(a singleton), but `set()` is only ever called internally - other threads have no way of calling `set()` and there are no public methods that can result in `set()` being called.

Comment: @Pentarctagon if `set` is called only once and it's complete *before* any of the reading threads starts reading then you should be good. Otherwise, the fact that `set` is called only internally doesn't matter because other threads might see stale values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - how would the reading threads see stale values, if `get()` always first refers to `SomeClass`'s current `hashlist` variable?

Comment: If the threads have a copy of the singleton *before* it finished running `set` it is considered as unsafe publication. I highly recommend reading: "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz, around chapter: "3.5. Safe Publication"