# Why variable visible to other thread without synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model, memory-model

I have theoretical question about memory visibility. Here is sample code:

```java
public class TwoThreadApp {

    private static class A {
        int x = 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws InterruptedException {
        A a = new A();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                if (a.x == 2) {
                    System.out.println(a.x);
                    return;
                }
                // IO operation which makes a.x visible to thread "t2"
                System.out.println("in loop");
            }
        });

        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        a.x = 2;
    }
}
```

1. Without `System.out.println("in loop")` programs works indefinitely, which is expected behavior.
2. But with `System.out.println("in loop")` it is always completes, which is not expected, because a.x is not volatile and there is no synchronized blocks.

My env: ubuntu 16.04, openjdk 1.8.0_131

Why it behaves this way?

Comment: The variable is always accessible (for read and write) becase it's static and in the same class. The synchronization is just a way to lock an object to ensure integrity.

Comment: Because `x` is cached, The JVM has this kind of optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

> Without System.out.println("in loop") programs works indefinitely, which is expected behavior.

On the contrary, the program should quit. The program keeps going, that is side-effect of fact that `x` is cached (as non volatile). The caching is compiler's optimalization and you should not rely on it (depending on JVM settings).

> But with System.out.println("in loop") it is always completes, which is not expected, because a.x is not volatile and there is no synchronized blocks.

This is IMHO expected behaviour. I cannot tell you why, I'd assume the IO operations are involved to clear the thread cache (please comment/correct if someone is having better insight).

Accessing variables without synchronization or locks or being volatile with multiple threads may be really unpredictable.

You can even disable many optimalizations with  `-Djava.compiler=NONE` (then the program should always quit as expected)

Comment: The main question is how IO operations involved in clearing thread cache.

Comment: That was only my assumption. If you'd decompile, the bytecode for println will state `ldc` (load static  data) and `invokevirtual` (call a method).  The caching is really *magic* done by JIT (just-in-time compiler). Simply using no volatile or synchronized you make the program unpredictable

Comment: @SergeyGalkin, it has nothing to do with IO, but with the happens-before relationship applied by the JVM.  The link to the duplicate response explains how println works (find "The effect of a print statement"), it includes a synchronized block.  As per the Java memory model (see. https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization): "Before we can enter a synchronized block, we acquire the monitor, which has the effect of invalidating the local processor cache so that variables will be reloaded from main memory."

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is something to do with Compiler optimization I think. In your first example compile can decide to move the If condition outside while loop like

```
if(a.x == 2) while(true) {...}
```

In 2nd case as you are using println which internally uses synchronized keyword compiler may not optimize the code as above.

This is what I think and I maybe wrong.

Edit: You can also refer here : [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement)