# Why does this code always print nothing after run for a while?

Tags: java, multithreading

I run the main method after a while, it will always print nothing.

But if I uncomment "System.out.println(111);" and "System.out.println(222);",it will run normal i think.

I fetch the dump of 'soldWorker' thread and 'refundWorker' thread, they stop at the `if` judge.

```
public class ProducerAndConsumer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyncTikcet2 syncTikcet = new SyncTikcet2(1);

        Runnable syncSoldTicket = () -> syncTikcet.soldTicket();
        Runnable syncRefundTicket = () -> syncTikcet.refund();

        new Thread(syncSoldTicket, "soldWorker").start();
        new Thread(syncRefundTicket, "refundWorker").start();
    }
 }

class SyncTikcet2 {

    private Integer ticketNum;

    public SyncTikcet2(Integer ticketNum) {
        this.ticketNum = ticketNum;
    }


    public void soldTicket() {
        while (true) {
            if (ticketNum > 0) {
                ticketNum = ticketNum - 1;
                System.out.println("sold ticket,the num is" + ticketNum);
            } else {
                // System.out.println(111);
            }
        }
    }

    public void refund() {
        while (true) {
            if (ticketNum == 0) {
                ticketNum = ticketNum + 1;
                System.out.println("refund ticket,the num is" + ticketNum);
            } else  {
                // System.out.println(222);
            }
        }
    }

    public Integer getTicketNum() {
        return ticketNum;
    }

    public void setTicketNum(Integer ticketNum) {
        this.ticketNum = ticketNum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't made the field volatile, there is no reason for a thread to re-read a value it didn't change.

Try using `private volatile int ticketNum`

I suggest using a primitive e.g. `int`, unless you have to use an Object reference. It's not only faster but it also makes it clear you don't expect the value to be `null`.

Comment: thank you very much, you are so great, your answer guide me to find another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement). This question is the same as mine and it's answer more detailed. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: @wr1ttenyuzhao note System.out.println has a `synchronized` memory barrier, however if it's not called you might not see an update.

Comment: yeah, this is why it will run normal when i uncomment "System.out.println(111);" and "System.out.println(222);", thank your answer, you are a good man, thanks