# JAVA Weird bug that gets fixed with "System.out.println("TEXT");"

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement, timedelta, system.out

I have my deltaTime loop ,in a MultiThreading program, that returns this void:

```java
public static void update(double deltaTime){
    // System.out.println("I am here");
    if(Key.W){
        Player.y -= deltaTime * Player.speed;
        System.out.println("Holding W | Adding : " + (deltaTime * Player.speed));
    }
}
```

The program is simple , to check if 'W' is hold and then ,if true, change players Y coordinates.

When I hold W , i get visual feedback that I am holding it , 
but the code from if statement (Key.W is TRUE for sure) is not being executed.

But it is not working unless i remove '//' from second line of code:

```java
public static void update(double deltaTime){
    System.out.println("I am here");
    if (Key.W) {
        Player.y -= deltaTime*Player.speed;
        System.out.println("Holding W | Adding : " + (deltaTime * Player.speed));
    }
}
```

Now it is working ... 
I get no errors in both scenarios , everything else is working :/

What can be the case of this weird bug ?

============================================

I got it working thanks to Andy Turner (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner)

If you have the same issue this helped me :

My variable Key.W was declared like this :

```java
Public static boolean W = false;
```

And to make it work I had to change Public to Volatile like this :

```java
volatile static boolean W = false;
```

To learn more about why it happens check this link :

[Loop doesn't see value changed by other thread without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-value-changed-by-other-thread-without-a-print-statement)

Comment: I'd guess that you're not declaring `Key.W` `volatile`?

Comment: Then how is if statement working when i add System.out.println("I am here"); in ?

Comment: `System.out.println` is typically internally synchronized (although it's not guaranteed); the synchronization creates the same happens-before effect.

Comment: I don't really understand how it affects the rest of the code ...

Comment: You don’t need to. All that matters, is that it is a side-effect you must not rely on. So fixing your code still is required. And reading a good book about concurrent programming before you continue writing multi-threaded code, is strongly recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help , adding Volatile instead of Public helped