# System.out.println updating local thread cache like volatile in java concurrency?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

I have a question in java concurrency.

I use the sout in `Producer` thread with class variable `private static boolean FLAG` and you can already see `FLAG` variable without **volatile**.

I want to change `FLAG = true` to `FLAG = !FLAG` in `Producer` thread and after that I expected to read this value in `Consumer` thread.

Ofcourse `FLAG` doesn’t have **volatile** and `Consumer` thread will read the old `FLAG` value.

So when I change position

`System.out.println("Flag to " + !FLAG);`

`FLAG = !FLAG;`

```
private static boolean FLAG = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Consumer().start();
    new Producer().start();
}

static class Consumer extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        boolean local = FLAG;

        while ( local ){

            local = FLAG;

            if (!local) {
                System.out.println("exit");
            }
        }

    }
}

static class Producer extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Flag to " + !FLAG);
        FLAG = !FLAG;
    }
}
```

to

```
private static boolean FLAG = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Consumer().start();
    new Producer().start();
}

static class Consumer extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        boolean local = FLAG;

        while ( local ){

            local = FLAG;

            if (!local) {
                System.out.println("exit");
            }
        }

    }
}

static class Producer extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        FLAG = !FLAG;
        System.out.println("Flag to " + !FLAG);
    }
}
```

`FLAG = !FLAG;`

`System.out.println("Flag to " + !FLAG);`

`Consumer` thread printing the " exit ".

So where is the my fault or what is the explanation this case.

Comment: (1) Possibly related: [Loop doesn't see value changed by other thread without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25425130) (2) Regarding `extends Thread` please see: [“implements Runnable” vs “extends Thread” in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541487).

Comment: `System.out.println` is typically implemented using synchronization (to avoid garbling the output of multiple threads printing at the same time), but it's not actually required. If you are using an implementation with synchronization, you do indeed get volatile-like behavior, because of the happens-before created by a synchronized block; however, this is not something you can rely upon happening.