# Problem with empty while, adding some random print fixes bug

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, awt

I was trying to get some info from user with GUI that runs in separate thread with Kotlin(Jvm). My attempt at doing this was ( minimal working example, I was not able to get rid of UI

```
import java.awt.*
import java.lang.Thread.sleep
import javax.swing.*


val board = Board()

fun main() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater {
        ThreadAnimationEx().isVisible = true
    }
    var test: String?=null
    board.instruction = {
        sleep(1000)
        test= "test value"
        println("Done")
    }
    while (test == null) {
        //uncommenting this line makes this work
//        sleep(100)
    }
    println("Finished with $test")
}



class ThreadAnimationEx() : JFrame() {
    init {
        add(board)
    }
}

class Board : JPanel(), Runnable {
    var instruction: (() -> Unit)? = null

    private var animator: Thread? = null

    override fun addNotify() {
        super.addNotify()
        animator = Thread(this)
        animator!!.start()
    }

    public override fun paintComponent(g: Graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(g)
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync()
    }

    override fun run() {
        while (true) {
            if (instruction != null) {
                instruction!!.invoke()
                instruction = null
            }
            sleep(10)
        }
    }
}
```

If the sleep(100) is not commented out then the program works correctly, prints

```
Done
Finished with test value
```

If there is no such fragment then I only get

```
Done
```

Is this some bug in kotlin or jvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's a bug in your program. There is nothing to indicate that the value of `test` will change, so the JVM is perfectly entitled to use a value cached in a register rather than fetching the value from memory when performing the test of the condition in the `while` loop.

You need to either use the `volatile` modifier on the `test` variable or use a type designed for concurrency such as [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

By the way, the reason that the call to `sleep` fixes it is presumably because there is some synchronization happening that causes a memory barrier which forces the value to be fetched again from memory. It is similar to why printing can also fix such a concurrency visibility problem, as explored in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-value-changed-by-other-thread-without-a-print-statement/25425131#25425131).