# print() make thread-local cache invalid?

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, jvm, volatile

In Java/Kotlin or any JVM languages, each thread has a "local memory" AKA. "Cache". When a thread want to write a variable into the memory, it first update the value in its own cache, then sync the modification into the Main Memory, which is shared between threads.

The following demo illustrates a use case that Thread unrealized changing happened:

```kotlin
class VolatileExample3 {

    var flag = false

    var a = 0

    fun write() {
        a = 1
        Thread.sleep(10)
        flag = true
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun test() {
            val example = VolatileExample3()
            val th = Thread {
                example.write()
            }
            th.start()
            while (!example.flag) {}
            println("a = ${example.a}")
        }
    }
}
```

The thread th calls the function `write()`, first update the value of `a`, then sleep for 10 ms as a  simulated IO operation, finally set flag as true indicating that the "write" has been done.

In Main thread, it always querying the value of flag and skip while loop when `flag` is true, which is ought to be the time that `write()` is over.

We want the output as "a = 1", which is the correct answer after writing.

However, because the "local memory / cache" exists, the Main Thread will loop around in `while` as if it was stuck.

[Main thread won't read Main Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p3fw.png)

Just before the content of `write()` run, main thread firstly read `flag` and get false, it won't get the value in Main Memory until we tell it explicitly.

Answer of the problem is obvious: add `@Volatile` to `flag`, in which the `READ` op onto it will make it's local memory invalid ahead of the real `LOAD VALUE`.

But I found another solution of this problem which is:

```kotlin
while (!example.flag) {
    print("")
}
```

It works without `@Volatile`! I wandered whether the `flush cache` operation inside `print()` would make the local memory / cache of Main Thread invalid or not. If so, what is the mechanism?

Also I found that putting `th.join()` before the while loop also works. Are these methods essentially the same, which means that the termination of a thread would be noticed to all other threads leading to the invalidation of local memory?

Comment: What you are talking about is how processors work. Without volatile, it is not that data will not be written to memory, it is that it is unpredictable when it will be written.  It is a fool's errand to try and enumerate all cases where 'unpredictable' works in your favour.  Just use proper synchronization.

Comment: Also, your use of 'invalidation' is strange. Memory is never 'invalid',  A cache may be invalid if memory has been updated and the processor cache now has stale contents -- e.g., because of I/O.  Writing cache content to memory invalidates neither cache nor memory.

Comment: You may want to have a look at read and write barriers (here for example: https://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency/). BTW, `print` (on JVM at least) calls `System.out.print` which internally uses `synchronised` that in turn flushes barriers.

Comment: @DavidSoroko Yes! I just got that point and try to add an empty syncronized block in the while loop and found it also works!

Comment: Also releveant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-value-changed-by-other-thread-without-a-print-statement

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your understanding of cache and memory is incorrect. On most architectures, from the perspective of the program, the cache is never invalid, a read from an address will always observe the most recent value at that address, and the cache coherency protocols will have to ensure that it is the case, regardless of multiple threads may read from/write to that memory address at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to this is that *according to the [Java Memory Model (JMM)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model)* which Kotlin on JVM depends on, your program is incorrect.

There is no *happens before* relationship between writing to `flag` in the child thread and subsequently reading it in the main thread.  The behavior of your application is unspecified: there are executions that are not *well-formed*.

From the language perspective, that means is that your "main" thread may or may not see `flag` change state.  The actual behavior *could* depend on your hardware platform (including how CPU type, many cores you have, how much RAM you have), the specific JRE version and build, or indeed ... anything.

Trying to understand how and why code *that is incorrect* changes behavior when you tweak it is kind of pointless.  You shouldn't write code like that anyway ... even if you think you know what is happening "under the hood".   The unspecified "under the hood" stuff could change, be different on different machines, and so on.

---

So what is actually going on?

Will it is hard to be sure, but I suspect that the `print` call is doing some synchronization of its own, and *that* has the serendipitous effect of causing memory caches to be flushed<sup>1</sup>.

But you can't rely on it.  The classes involved are not *specified* to have this effect.  It is a lucky implementation detail.

Note: since `flag` is not declared as `volatile`, it would be a legitimate<sup>2</sup> optimization for the JIT compiler to detect that there is no *happens before* relationship and then emit code that read `flag` from RAM and put it into a register *once*.  If it did that, the `print("");` hack would have no effect.

<sup>1 - Assuming that memory caches are involved.  There are other possible *mechanisms* in play too; e.g. use of registers.

2 - Legitimate in the sense that it doesn't violate the JMM visibility guarantees.  They only apply to *well-formed executions*!</sup>

Comment: print() in Kotlin calls `System.out.print()` in Java and finally uses `syncronized` internally. It also works when I add an empty `syncronized` block in the while loop. When a thread try to retrieve lock through syncronized, it will make its own thread memory invalid. I think this is what really happened.

Comment: Well yes.  But my point is that it is not *specified* anywhere that `System.out.print()` uses `synchronized` internally.

Comment: *It is a lucky implementation detail.*   No no no - something that causes incorrect code to look as if it works is an **unlucky** implementation detail  :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "cache" in the Java programming language. Caches are part of the underlying computer hardware architecture, and they work differently on different computers.

You job, as a Java programmer, is to make sure that your code obeys the rules that are published in [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) (JLS). The job of the developers who provide the Java compiler (`javac`), the Java virtual machine (JVM), and the Java run-time environment (JRE) for your particular computer is to ensure that if *your* code obeys the rules in the JLS, then *their* code will keep the promises made by the JLS.

Last time I looked, the rules and promises regarding access to variables from multiple threads were mostly in Chapter 17 and, mostly expressed in terms of "synchronization" and "happens before" relationships.

> I found another solution of this problem which is:...`print()`

That may work on *your* computer, with the operating system version and the JDK version that you happen to be using today. In fact, it works for a lot of people and many different computers, but it is not *guaranteed* to work.

Experimentation is not the way to find out what "works" and what does not. I once worked for a large corporation that released a major software package that broke the rules. It passed several weeks worth of aggressive testing in our offices. It even "worked" on all of our customer's computers when we first released it. But then, one of our customers upgraded their OS, and the software stopped working for them.

> Also I found that putting th.join() before the while loop also works.

That *is* guaranteed to work. The JLS explicitly guarantees that whatever thread A does to shared variables must become visible to any other thread after the other thread has called `A.join()`. In the language of the JLS, everything that thread A does "happens before" an `A.join()` call returns in the other thread.

Comment: When I say "local memory" or "cache", it represents the "Thread-own part" memory(in JMM) instead of the shared one. Through [this](https://medium.com/@MrAndroid/java-multithreading-part-1-java-memory-model-fb8e0cfab9d3) we know that in JMM(Java Memory Model) there does exists some spaces that belongs to only one thread and other spaces that is accessible to all threads. `volatile`, `syncronized` etc. are also capable of ensuring the consistency among threads, by invalidating the "thread-own part" and fetching from the "shared part".

Comment: Sure, there is thread-local memory, and stacks (in 'global' memory) tend to be accessed only by one thread.  But that has nothing at all to do with the matter of processor memory caches.  You appear to believe that data can be cached in 'local' memory and then copied to 'global' memory by explicit action.

Answer (score 0):

The two answers [by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77773375/642706) and [by Solomon Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77773194/642706) are both correct.

### `AtomicBoolean` instead of `volatile`

My preferred solution to your issue is the use of the `Atomic…` classes. Use of these classes clearly remind the reader that we are protecting access across threads.

To hold a Boolean value, use `AtomicBoolean`.

By changing your `Boolean` variable to a `AtomicBoolean`, you’ll not need `volatile`.

I don’t know Kotlin syntax but I’ll make an attempt at revising your code. Here we achieve thread-safety without any need for `volatile`.

```java
class VolatileExample3 {

    var flag = AtomicBoolean( false )

    var a = 0

    fun write() {
        a = 1
        Thread.sleep(10)
        flag.set ( true )
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun test() {
            val example = VolatileExample3()
            val th = Thread {
                example.write()
            }
            th.start()
            while ( ! example.flag.get() ) {}
            println("a = ${example.a}")
        }
    }
}
```

---

Of course your code has another concurrency issue. There is a gap in time between execution of the the `while` and the `println`. During that time the flag could be flipped. But that seems to be outside the scope of your Question.