Understanding Multithreading Behavior in Java: Inconsistent Output in Counter Program
I'm currently learning about multithreading in Java and encountered an interesting behavior that I'm struggling to understand. I have a simple Java program that utilizes multithreading to increment a counter, but I'm getting inconsistent output based on the placement of print statements in the code.
class Counter{
    int count=1;
    public void increment(){
        count++;
    }
}
public class test {
   
    public static void main(String[] args)  {


        Counter counter1= new Counter();

        Runnable obj1 = ()->{
            for(int i=0; i<1000;i++)
            {
                counter1.increment();
               //System.out.println("obj1 : "+ counter1.count);

            }
        };
        Runnable obj2 =  ()->{
            for(int i=0; i<1000;i++)
            {
                counter1.increment();
             //   System.out.println("obj2 : "+counter1.count);
    
            }
        };
     //   System.out.println(counter1.count);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj1);
    //    System.out.println(counter1.count);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj2);
    //    System.out.println(counter1.count);

        t1.start();
      // System.out.println(counter1.count);

        t2.start();

        System.out.println("result is :" + counter1.count);

}}


When I comment out all the System.out.println(counter1.count); statements except the last one, I consistently get 1 as the output. However, when I keep all the print statements, I get varying output like 577, which seems to be the result of both threads' increments.
Could someone please help me understand why this inconsistency occurs? I'm particularly interested in why commenting out the print statements affects the final output of the program.
Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You don't wait for the threads to run to completion and you do not synchronize access to the count variable.

Check out The Java™ Tutorials on Synchronization

the result is probably being printed even before the threads get a chance to start running

In addition to the other possibilities mentioned, println introduces synchronization that can change the results, see  https://stackoverflow.com/q/25425130/217324

You haven't synchronised on the counter and System.out.println is synchronized and it takes a lot longer to run than increment. There are many duplicates  a few if you search on [Java] thread System.out.println

When you are uncommenting the lines, Code prints 1 Because of below reasons

please note that when you are calling t1.start() and t2.start() then only Thread gets created and run() method of Runnable will get execute.

When run() method executes then compiler will increment the counter. Before that compiler will print pre-initialized value of counter variable.

Calling start() on a Thread doesn't necessarily result in the thread running immediately after. Other things can execute/happen between your calling start() and the first line of your thread's run() method being run. And even once your run() method is running, it's also possible that other things happen before, during, or after your run() method finishes.


